# Awesome WM does not maximize windows anymore

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

Yesterday my awesome configuration was able to maximize window (in any layout I use (tiled/floating)) but now the maximize command does exactly nothing.

I've looked config file (`rc.lua`) and did not found any incorrect code there.

Here is my client keys:

```
clientkeys = awful.util.table.join(
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "f",      function (c) c.fullscreen = not c.fullscreen  end),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "c",      function (c) c:kill()                         end),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "space",  awful.client.floating.toggle                     ),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "Return", function (c) c:swap(awful.client.getmaster()) end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "o",      awful.client.movetoscreen                        ),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "r",      function (c) c:redraw()                       end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "t",      function (c) c.ontop = not c.ontop            end),
    awful.key({ modkey            }, "F7",     function(c) c.maximized_horizontal = not c.maximized_horizontal end),
    awful.key({ modkey            }, "F8",     function(c) c.maximized_vertical   = not c.maximized_vertical end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "n",
        function (c)
            -- The client currently has the input focus, so it cannot be
            -- minimized, since minimized clients can't have the focus.
            c.minimized = true
        end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "m",
        function (c)
            c.maximized_horizontal = not c.maximized_horizontal
            c.maximized_vertical   = not c.maximized_vertical
        end)
)
```

The most interesting here is that `modkey + F7` and `modkey + F8` both work and these hotkeys are able to maximize window (but I need both them in one), but `modkey + m` does not work.

`awesome -k` says everything is okay.

Can someone please help in investigating what is wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you push `modkey + m`? Are there print/logging functions you can use in that function to confirm that it is being called correctly?

Comment: Have you mapped anything else to `modkey + m`?

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but for the sake of investigaing everything, I have to ask: did you try to restart `awesome` itself (Usually `modkey +  Ctrl + r`)? And did you modify your `rc.lua` or did this just stop working? Any system updates?

Comment: @Slizzered yes I did, a lot of times. And even restarting by killing the process totally. Also, `rc.lua` parses fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing : check if the shortcut is really executed :

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "m",
    function (c)
        naughty.notify({text="ok go"})
        c.maximized_horizontal = not c.maximized_horizontal
        c.maximized_vertical   = not c.maximized_vertical
    end)
```

then you can do more investigations

Comment: That's a nice tip! I unintentionally mapped another command to modkey + m, and found out using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, google brought me here. My root cause was different.

If you're using more than one layout (especially non-Latin based one), please check that whenever you're hitting the hotkey, awesome wm is set to English (or Latin) layout. Otherwise awesome wm hotkeys won't get triggered and you'll end up tearing hairs on your head after a good hour of investigations like I did :)